# How to add cookie consent div on top

Tags: html, css

The problem I have is that I can not place the cookie consent on top of the page for mobile devices. The CSS works fine for bigger screens

```css
.cookie-container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2f3640;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.39);
  z-index: 10000 !important;
  transition: 400ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="cookie-container">
  <p>
    Αυτή η ιστοσελίδα χρησιμοποιεί cookies. <a href="cookies.html" target="_blank">Περισσότερες πληροφορίες</a>.
  </p>

  <button class="cookie-btn">
    Εντάξει, το κατάλαβα !
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tell us which browser does it concern ? Because it seems to work fine this way, or share more code from your page

Comment: Chrome browser. On mobile devices div seems to be fixed at the bottom of the page

Comment: ok because on iOS safari it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe your question more clearly?

If you meant to keep your div intact at the top my being fixed to its position then it already is fixed and it works fine for mobile devices also!

```css
.cookie-container {
  position: fixed;

  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: #2f3640;
  color: #f5f6fa;
  padding: 0 32px;
  box-shadow: 0 -2px 16px rgba(47, 54, 64, 0.39);
  z-index: 10000 !important;
  transition: 400ms;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="cookie-container">
  <p>
    Αυτή η ιστοσελίδα χρησιμοποιεί cookies. <a href="cookies.html" target="_blank">Περισσότερες πληροφορίες</a>.
  </p>

  <button class="cookie-btn">
    Εντάξει, το κατάλαβα !
  </button>
</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque, asperiores nam suscipit numquam provident nostrum iste harum, eveniet quidem quasi praesentium obcaecati saepe ea. Laudantium voluptate maiores explicabo ex amet!
Veritatis suscipit voluptatum voluptates adipisci distinctio, excepturi dignissimos error atque iure impedit accusamus, officiis neque saepe, sapiente debitis expedita explicabo eos sequi soluta dolore necessitatibus! Officiis repellat quos eligendi vel.
Maxime, impedit et! Dignissimos fugiat reprehenderit blanditiis animi quos reiciendis numquam, sunt minima veritatis ad saepe corrupti nisi eaque incidunt? Libero distinctio magnam expedita ex omnis. Odio sed assumenda magnam.
Sit quasi quia eos quod assumenda libero maiores consequuntur expedita ea, quo exercitationem, placeat deleniti debitis. Unde in atque inventore, hic aut ducimus fugit! Molestias sint officia quidem at asperiores.
Facilis neque iure eos dolorem aperiam, aliquam libero unde inventore repellat amet, recusandae harum corporis! Id recusandae sunt ea possimus nam aut. Cum eius perspiciatis excepturi, optio sint adipisci molestias.
Quia sint qui illo sit ea autem modi dolorem fuga velit harum eveniet aut consectetur ut, eligendi vitae, saepe asperiores natus quae rerum recusandae dolor. Dignissimos illum voluptas pariatur similique.
Illo corrupti iusto repudiandae pariatur quasi! Iure maxime atque maiores? Dicta minima officiis autem inventore, exercitationem voluptatum nisi expedita quidem facilis a consequuntur veniam repellat sapiente id! Libero, magnam sunt!
Vitae neque delectus impedit, numquam molestias labore quam officia modi repudiandae natus? Tempora nobis, ab facilis beatae facere asperiores qui, similique dolore dicta ipsum repellat saepe aliquam quaerat omnis eligendi.
Illum vero harum delectus, voluptas reiciendis iure! Natus nulla ipsum in labore, perferendis eius esse dolorum necessitatibus exercitationem quae quibusdam vero, debitis saepe amet doloremque! Cupiditate a accusantium quasi officiis.
Ratione fuga magni obcaecati consectetur laboriosam aut nisi. Adipisci, culpa vel corrupti eum mollitia nemo pariatur harum reprehenderit ipsam placeat laudantium expedita facilis, aut, voluptatem quo quod esse accusamus officiis!
Suscipit magni porro architecto est, fuga hic cumque recusandae quo veniam eos! Laudantium, quisquam quae explicabo delectus rerum id deserunt nulla voluptates aliquam tenetur recusandae cum incidunt quasi tempore! Consequuntur?
Natus minus quos dolorum, non aspernatur qui est, asperiores distinctio iste corrupti vero cupiditate consectetur ad quo, adipisci numquam suscipit officiis dolore deserunt? Amet assumenda aut accusantium minima eveniet reiciendis.
Quos, dolorum possimus laboriosam hic ipsum perspiciatis! Temporibus tempora praesentium iste, impedit error provident commodi. Alias ipsa, a corporis repudiandae, tempora totam tenetur voluptatum sint, delectus odit iste hic fuga!
Rerum minus numquam ipsa. Dicta, eligendi. In velit obcaecati maxime excepturi minus enim est exercitationem corporis inventore? Eius, praesentium! Nisi reiciendis iste tempore maiores nesciunt eligendi repellendus molestiae in natus!
Possimus temporibus quam asperiores aliquid dicta maiores dolores ratione aut voluptatem provident, quod eveniet ipsa? Quis, repudiandae. Quas, magnam, sit nam iste eaque nostrum et, veniam vero fugit a perferendis?
Provident modi delectus neque sunt voluptas, rerum voluptatibus, error dicta saepe aliquid quaerat molestias cupiditate incidunt a, sit eaque ab est ut vitae totam temporibus ipsam natus molestiae tempore. Facilis!
Maxime, exercitationem quae molestiae esse consectetur doloremque sed quasi inventore assumenda ipsam qui corporis dicta ad libero similique laborum neque omnis illum odit minima? Quas quia quae repellendus minima perspiciatis?
Fugit ab cum eius nihil quis assumenda! Eum ut perferendis error sapiente voluptatibus sequi magnam provident deserunt in ex explicabo assumenda rerum quos fugiat, cum aspernatur necessitatibus illo maiores fuga.
Nam, recusandae magnam animi, numquam commodi optio quos omnis est facilis laborum dolorum totam. Porro asperiores omnis tempore quo molestiae sit, fuga totam eum libero ea dolorum aliquam aspernatur dolore.
Repellat voluptate nam magnam itaque, maiores quidem voluptatibus rerum delectus reiciendis recusandae sunt sint ratione facilis eos quisquam animi. Harum rerum veniam repellendus ab reprehenderit. Praesentium dolor qui doloremque molestias?
Iste fuga esse eveniet commodi asperiores eum aspernatur voluptatem tempore ut temporibus dolores reprehenderit possimus, laboriosam accusantium labore? Doloribus vero architecto nihil laborum sapiente impedit, magni delectus doloremque et saepe?
Corporis aperiam officiis amet explicabo consectetur sunt tenetur. Earum deserunt maxime quae deleniti reiciendis, impedit incidunt voluptatum. Veniam assumenda accusamus quas. Sed fuga ea quasi vel nostrum, a reprehenderit repudiandae?
Vel quibusdam maxime laborum eius obcaecati. Dignissimos sit quisquam, consequuntur dolore, vero, aliquam fugit accusantium tempora voluptatem cumque sunt natus eum rerum. Accusamus quidem eos saepe optio minus animi qui.
Excepturi voluptatem eum, unde repudiandae cupiditate possimus maiores illum ex ea sapiente at porro neque totam iusto quae quis tempore velit doloribus! Asperiores id sint et optio vero facere quos!
Perspiciatis natus accusantium voluptate? Ab, repudiandae explicabo. Vero earum sapiente dolorum! Sequi repellendus corrupti nobis enim deleniti. Culpa necessitatibus ullam repellendus? Dolor at quaerat earum obcaecati eligendi, possimus beatae a?
Voluptatem reprehenderit hic consequuntur, quas enim quia cupiditate quos expedita iusto explicabo, minus nobis accusantium ea labore! Rem facilis, fugiat enim voluptatem odit in obcaecati, dolores, eaque perferendis est aspernatur.
Modi numquam non sint, cum aperiam quis quae ipsa minus nihil, voluptates nulla accusantium doloremque debitis repudiandae nesciunt labore possimus consequuntur aspernatur illo error quidem neque aliquid? Corporis, repellat voluptatibus.
Maiores repellendus ipsum culpa quas, veritatis dolorem perspiciatis et placeat qui consequatur praesentium! Repudiandae perferendis, dolor ducimus, labore culpa ipsam obcaecati consequatur odit fugiat magni modi voluptas! Culpa, porro impedit.
Aspernatur perferendis consequatur molestias beatae veniam, suscipit, sapiente non voluptatibus magnam ex vel deserunt tenetur nihil, unde reiciendis adipisci repudiandae cupiditate placeat qui? Aut sunt quo eligendi corporis dolore perspiciatis.
Eaque praesentium iure dolor itaque distinctio sapiente excepturi saepe explicabo! Sed cumque iusto illum tempore nesciunt excepturi ipsum iure consectetur, omnis, tenetur consequatur provident! Quia minima sit in dolores deleniti?
Unde quos voluptas nesciunt eius excepturi vel dolores at vitae adipisci, consequatur eveniet illo doloremque culpa atque nihil quo itaque aspernatur delectus iste iusto sint ex? Eos a consequatur molestias!
Quibusdam quasi similique recusandae maxime voluptates id dolore eos totam alias eveniet fuga nam tempore cupiditate nesciunt harum doloribus, ratione inventore minus quo? Reiciendis perferendis tempore cum suscipit, eaque tempora?
Excepturi ab quibusdam tempore ut iste dolore ipsum tenetur explicabo corrupti nam optio ipsa eligendi maiores ad, perspiciatis et laborum esse asperiores libero a repellendus accusamus? Reiciendis voluptatem et doloremque!
Nemo nobis atque laudantium eaque veniam veritatis adipisci exercitationem vero tempore fugit autem temporibus pariatur excepturi iste laborum repellat voluptates quidem mollitia, ipsam nesciunt quod! Sunt quos sequi beatae praesentium?
Provident reprehenderit beatae voluptates fuga harum impedit culpa maiores, tempora minus cum? Enim veritatis vero, accusantium asperiores adipisci consectetur autem ex excepturi, odio in, natus quae labore. Quidem, inventore saepe.
Rerum dicta incidunt tenetur molestias autem eaque! Corporis iure dolore quae minima nobis praesentium impedit aspernatur quam sequi eveniet temporibus dolor ducimus, soluta voluptatibus unde consequatur, sed id expedita doloribus?
Saepe tempora aut iste officia possimus autem quos aliquid, asperiores, neque maiores magni minus. Nisi, a? Magni qui, doloribus ut accusamus hic officiis repellendus expedita suscipit laboriosam? Ad, consequatur quo.
Mollitia quas, alias officia quis, perferendis cum dolore vero expedita quae id inventore? Numquam cumque explicabo assumenda incidunt aperiam. Temporibus reiciendis dolores enim incidunt nesciunt reprehenderit doloribus maiores sunt aperiam.
Dolores magni recusandae harum perspiciatis, quibusdam tempora corporis dolorum perferendis ipsum vel doloribus ipsam, rerum itaque laudantium. Modi similique officia sed? Amet facere necessitatibus consequatur quaerat corrupti odio minus aperiam!
Esse labore saepe unde doloribus nesciunt iusto accusamus voluptatibus assumenda deleniti enim alias repellat laudantium veritatis blanditiis omnis tenetur eum facilis voluptatum voluptates quia, qui similique ab ratione. Aut, officiis!
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You wrote "Can you describe your answer more nicely?" I guess you meant question instead of answer